# validate a parameter from querystring

Tags: perl

Hi I am very new to perl. as you can see in my code below, I need to fetch a parameter "page" from querystring. and I also want to validate the parameter value.  if the parameter is not in querystring or not a number, then assign 1 to $current_page, else just assign the value to $current_page. how can I do this in perl? please help me.

```
use strict;

use CGI qw/:standard/;
my $querystring = CGI::Vars();

my $current_page = $querystring->{page};

print $current_page;  # I would get a warning "Use of uninitialized value..."
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will use `1` if the param is missing:

```
my $current_page = $querystring->{page} || 1;
```

It won't check to make sure it's a number, though. That would be something like:

```
my $current_page = $querystring->{page};
$current_page = 1
   if !defined($current_page)
   || $current_page =~ /[^0-9]/
   || $current_page == 0;
```

If you need to validate multiple parameters, you might want something like [Data::FormValidator](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data%3a%3aFormValidator). Once you start using it, you get all of its benefits including the ability to trim leading and trailing spaces for example.

Comment: `//` requires perl v5.10. You can use `||` if you have an older version of perl than that.

Comment: Looks like zero and the empty string are not acceptable anyway, so I switched to `||`.